# How to set python path in windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7

I try to set path of python in windows 7, but I can not do that. 
I go to:

```
 My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced > Environment Variables
```

but I don't know what to do now.
please help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1.Click on Environment Variables

2.On System Variables section find  variable and select it

3.Press Edit button

4.In Variable value section add your python path (like: ;c:\python27) at end of string

5.; is separator for different paths

[image]

Comment: Remember that the folder is called `c:\Python27` by default.

Comment: LOL, you had "c:pytohn27" in your path... :)